# How do I replicate the following facetwrap ggplot image for more columns in my dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

The code below creates a set of 16 ggplot bar charts from my dataframe (df) using the first 16 columns in my dataframe. I would like to replicate this for the next 16 columns in my dataframe and get another image with 16 bar charts on them. Ultimately I'd like to do all columns in my dataframe (which has 100+ columns). How do I specify all columns while at the same time breaking them into chunks of 16 as with my initial image (without manually copying this code and changing the column range each time)? Thanks!

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(1:16)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., group = name), stat = "count", fill = "#f68060", alpha =.6, width = .4) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: You might be interested in something like package **ggforce** `facet_wrap_paginate()` for this sort of task.

Comment: @aosmith, thank you. Would you be able to provide an example on how facet_wrap_paginate() would be used in this case? Would I create a loop and create an image with facet wrap each time? Or as a one time operation across all columns?

Answer (score 0):

Lacking your `df`, here's a quick walk-through of `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate` using `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate("cyl", ncol = 1, nrow = 2, page = 1)
npages <- ggforce::n_pages(gg)
npages
# [1] 2

print(gg)
for (pg in seq_len(npages)[-1]) {
  gg <- gg + ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate("cyl", ncol = 1, nrow = 2, page = pg)
  print(gg)
}
```

Produces

> [image: first page]

and then

> [image: second page]

If you accidentally go too far, it will err:

```r
gg + ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate("cyl", ncol = 1, nrow = 2, page = 3)
# Warning in min(layout$ROW) :
#   no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# Warning in max(layout$COL) :
#   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
# Warning in max(layout$ROW) :
#   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
# Warning in matrix(list(zeroGrob()), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol) :
#   NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
# Error in matrix(list(zeroGrob()), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol) : 
#   invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
```